# How to develop a phone app backend for an "in development" website in asp.net

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, azure, mobile

I am developing an **City Guide** website with ASP.NET MVC, a DB (probably SQLServer), Bootstrap as a CSS framework and it will (probably) hosted in Azure.
This website will be fully responsive, but, later we will need a native phone app.
How can i develop my website backend keeping in mind that after we launch the website we will need to use its backend for a mobile APP?

Comment: Are you familiar with REST API's? Instead of using MVC to render your views, you can use Web API to create a REST style application so that all communication is done over that API. Then your web front end and native app can both communicate over that API.

Comment: hi @mason i know the concept but not the details, will study this approach in .Net ecossystem.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's very broad and opinion-soliciting. There's simply no right answer to this, nor is there a single right approach.

Comment: @Ewerton If it's a simple backend you can add WEB API to your MVC project.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options to achieve that on azure depending on what are you looking for.

### option 1 [Azure Mobile App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/mobile/)

With this azure service you can create a backend optimized for mobile aplications, there you can find features that will ease a lot your development tasks like:

- Authentication thru social networks and active directory
- Push notifications with

  - Apple APN
  - android ASN
  - Windows WNS
- automated table creation and management,  not mandatory you can also modify the schema by yourself.
- Syncronization for offline or transient network conditions
- Dynamic data schema (optional)
- scalability
- automated scalability
- You'll have SDKs for different Mobile clients like

  - Javascript
  - .Net
  - Windows /Windows Mobile
  - iOS
  - Android
  - Apache Cordova
  - The backend could be developed in two different options
  - .Net
  - Node JS

### option 2 [Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/web/)

You can create your WebAPI and host that on Azure. You can get into your application all features you'll need but you need to code all by yourself.

- automatic scalability
- All web Apps features (most (if not all) of them exists in Mobile Apps)

### option 3 [Azure VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/virtual-machines/)

Finally you can host your backend in a Virtual Machine, here you have full control of everithing (it's your machine) but also you'll need to manage and code everything by yourself.

### My **reccommendation**

is to use **Azure Mobile Apps**. The code to use this sevice is pretty easy because it's like an ASP.NEt web API, more especialized and depending on azure Mobile Apps, but you'll save a lot of time coding and testing code because the 
platform offers those features .

Also, I guess you can use  your mobile App service backend from other .net applications including websites, you could use "managed client for Azure Mobile Apps"   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/

Comment: Awesome answer @JuanK, just one question, i am concerned about using the backend for both website and mobile app, using Azure Mobile Apps is it possible?

Comment: @Ewerton Yeah, I guess you can use  your mobile App service backend from other .net applications including websites, you could use "managed client for Azure Mobile Apps"   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/

Answer (score 0):

I usually go for mobile first approach anyway what i would do if it was the other way around

1. Make sure to add components required for mobile devices while developing your models
2. Make sure to add a WebApi that is required for the mobile devices
3. Make sure your authentication supports OAuth (Better for mobile users)